# Tooltip using css only

Tags: html, css

I have an application on which I can only change the CSS.
e.g.

```
<p class="abc">My Text</p>
```

I can only change the **abc** in the above text or can add another css class along abc.
Is there any way to display a tool tip by editing properties of abc in css? 
I can edit the css file only. 
Even the tool tip text have to be placed in css or the css can refer it from anywhere else. 
Any possibility?

Comment: What would the tooltip text be? Would it be different for every element / class?

Comment: Also, if you can change the class, why can't you change the HTML? It's the same thing. Your question is not logical.

Comment: Can you add anything else besides `class`? to the HTML?

Comment: @Paulie_D Tool tip text would be different for different fields. I can add different classes for each field I need tooltip for. The html is generated by a software which we have no control over. That software however let's us assign classes to elements.

Comment: @Aziz I cannot add anything else besides class

Comment: Try to make the class name equal to `abc" title="tooltip`. By the way, if that works, the application isn't protected against XSS attacks.

Comment: @AhmedRana in that case you could try to strip the class letters with negative text-indent offset - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can it be done with pure CSS? **Yes**. However, with JavaScript you get much more control.

```css
body { margin: 3em; }

.tooltip { position: relative; }

.tooltip::before {
  content: "\2003" attr(class); /* print em-space with class text */
  text-indent: -3.9em; /* add negative text offset to hide class name */
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute; bottom: 50%;
  background: #000; color: #FFF; padding: 5px; border-radius: 5px;
  opacity:0; transition:0.3s; overflow:hidden;
  max-width: 50%; /* avoids very long sentences */
  pointer-events: none; /* prevents tooltip from firing on pseudo hover */
}

.tooltip:hover::before { opacity:1; bottom: 100%; }
```

```html
<p class="tooltip Tooltip Text">My Text</p>
<p class="tooltip Dolor sit amet bla bla">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Basically I added an *em space** and set a negative `text-indent` with `overflow:hidden` to hide the first part of text so that `tooltip My Text here` becomes `My Text here`. This is a bit hacky and you'll have to be careful of class name conflicts.

* The em-space is used to allow for some left padding.

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/gs1ye10r/2/

Comment: I have a question. If I write a long line of text. It stretches the tooltip. 
Is it possible to break line in the tooltip or make any section of text bold?

Comment: @AhmedRana yes - you can add `max-width` property to the pseduo element - https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/gs1ye10r/2/ I also added `pointer-events: none` so that the tooltip when fire by accident

Comment: It is working fine in JSFiddle but unfortunately on my css it isn't working (may be due to some other conflicting rule). Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Use the devtools inspector to check which what CSS is being applied. If there is a class in CSS that conflicts you could add the `:not` pseudo selector, like `.hello:not(.tooltip)`

Comment: Hi @Aziz Is there a way to use richtext or html in the tooltip. I tried using <br> inside a toolip but it only shows as <br> not a new line

Comment: @AhmedRana no, you can't parse HTML with CSS content - you'll have to either employ a JS solution or change the HTML structure

Answer (score -3):

Look at this page http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I cannot add this span tag :(

Comment: Why can you not do that?

Comment: @mlegg read the question carefully, OP can only modify the class name in HTML.

Comment: oh, sorry, missed that